# Update part of interface with "unknown" data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

App in React and Typescript.

I have a data structure like this

```
export interface data {
  name1: ConfigurationVariable,
  name2: ConfigurationVariable,
  name3: ConfigurationVariable,
  name4: ConfigurationVariable,
}
```

and

```
export interface ConfigurationVariable {
  id: string;
  value: any;
  name: string;
  type: DataTypes;
  default: DataType;
  min: number | string | boolean;
  max: DataType;
  storage: StorageType; 
}
```

In my app I have a variable in useState of type **data**.

```
const [CVData, setCVData] = useState<data>(CV);
```

My app receives websocket messages like this: {name: any, value: any}.
E.g. {name: name2, value: 100}

How should I update the right value in my data state, in this case value for **name2**

Is there a better way to store my values? They will be updated a lot.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const {name, ...rest }  = datafromWebSocket
setCVData(cvData=>({...cvData, [name]: {...cvData[name], ...rest}}))
```

Data structure seems correct. It should be this easy to update with this structure. please let me know if it does not work or I missed something.

Comment: I got:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'CVInterface'.

...cvData[name]

I also tried to cast name to a string but it doesn't like that either. 
If I set 
const name = 'name2'

it works

Comment: ```CVInterface``` is nowhere in code you have posted. Error seems to be with typescript. 
Try this instead. 
```const {name, value}  = datafromWebSocket
setCVData(cvData=>({...cvData, [name]: {...cvData[name], value}}))
```

Comment: Oh sorry. It should be 'data'. 
I'm trying this. I still get:


Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'data'.    ts(7053)

Comment: Can you create a sandbox ? Otherwise we will be doing trials and errors.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-tesla-6oiwl?file=/src/App.tsx

It works but i get an error.

Comment: Your data interface needed change. Working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wood-4r2ez?file=/src/App.tsx:235-300). ```export interface data {
  [key: string]: ConfigurationVariable;
}```